# How to read parent attributes in Vue3 typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

In the child component I am trying to write, I need to get the parent object. The commented out lines don't work.

AccordionState is:

```
export type AccordionKeys = | "open" | "disabled";

export type AccordionState = {
    [key: string]: {[key in AccordionKeys]: boolean; };
}
```

The child code is:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { AccordionState } from "@/types/global";
    import { defineComponent, useAttrs } from "vue";

    export default defineComponent({
      name: "AccordionPane",
      props: {
        panelName: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
      },
      computed: {
        open(): boolean {
          // const attrs = useAttrs();
          // const state = attrs.state as AccordionState;
          // return state[this.panelName].open && !state[this.panelName].disabled;
          return true;
        },
    disabled(): boolean {
      // const attrs = useAttrs();
      // const state = attrs.state as AccordionState;
      // return state[this.panelName].disabled;

      return false;
    },
```

**The parent component.** The computed getProps here shows that I am defining prop.state correctly, but the commented code in the AccordionPane does not work. the variable "state" is null. I don't see a lot of typescript examples online, and the javascript examples are so unstructured I don't know how to adapt them to typescript.

```
  <template>
    <div class="accordionControl">
      <slot ref="content"></slot>
    </div>
    <textarea class="debug" v-model="getProps"></textarea>
  </template>

  <script lang="ts">

  import { type AccordionState } from '@/types/global';
  import { defineComponent, type PropType } from 'vue';

  export default defineComponent({
    name: "AccordionControl",
    props: {
      state: {
        type: Object as PropType<AccordionState>,
        required: true,
      },
      isVert: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
      allOpen: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      }
    },
    computed: {
      getProps(): string {
        return JSON.stringify(this.$props, null, '  ');
      }
    }
  });
  </script>
```

The following link is one of the javascript examples and it works.

https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp1kDFrwzAQhf/K9RY5YGTaMbUL2ToWOnSoOtjxORhkSUhyl5D/3pMVXCcQ0KDHvfse9854cE7+zoR7rMPRjy5CoDi7N2XGyVkf4QyeBrjA4O0Egq1CGWWO1oQIUzhBk+aFeCetLXy1oc/Pet0/id2K+dRjTz5TFMoq6xSt8DUR6yrnczKLSJPTbSRWAPV1uWsUviiEfcufZ/7k6ZXFoq7WPSzxPyJdtyFKKW+8S+Kj63saRkMf3rpQwhzoEKMPd31oiuCSg9vY+Itv0YmfHZ+XDO2y2KyMgstJNVpNUttTsQBkV2ajbHm86QQvf3ztlVg=

Comment: I have a workaround, I can inject the state into the children. But it would be less markup if this can work just automatically inheriting the state

Comment: Why do you _need_ to access the parent component directly? Could you not use props or provide/inject? Is it simply because it would be more code?

Comment: I don't want a brittle element that has to be configured in parallel. Other controls I've found don't do that, so there is a way to do this. All the ones I found do one of the things I don't like, such as let you open a panel without closing the others, or they use a rather monstrous bootstrap-based mess to implement it.

I've used inject before to tie several separate elements to use the same data, but the service just automagically connects things out without any dependency on the parent.
I'm still refining the service, I will post what I did for review real soon now.

Comment: Generally props are used to send data from parent to child. See [VueSfcExample](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp1Uc1qhDAQfpVpLnFBlPa41YI99VjooYemh7iOixBNSOJexHfvjFmsFAo5ZPL9JV8W0ThX3GYUZ1GFix9chIBxdi9qGkZnfYQFPPawQu/tCJKoUk1qutgpRBjDFWrGM/mGxlj41KFLy3rTPcjTbvNhhg59clGiKNPM0Uo8s2NVpnxKpiHi6IyOSBNAdRe3tRJPSsBZ0+aRNgm9e9FQlbtO5OI3gl93cFSx6obbJgZ4PcOytOvKxwS0vtwYKjYMaAY4IwkOAds1/6usw36Y8N1bF3KYAzYx+vCnRIMRHDOowgM/+5KtzEFq+X2iYpilN3W9G2VUK3+ANVgYe802l6LNE7HQBB/aFOsP7NiowQ==). If props can't help then you can use `getCurrentInstance` helper from `vue` which has complete information about the parent.

Comment: At this point i would use a event based communication between components, for example using mitt

Comment: This is a XY problem. Rather than asking about how to implement a particular pattern, you might want to ask about how to solve the actual problem. What is the functionality you're trying to implement?

Comment: This works in JavaScript like I said but not in typescript. I have solved the problem and will post an answer.

Comment: getCurrentInstance is an internal Vue function, and is subject to change, it is exported, but it's not intended to be used by application developers because they may change anything they want in it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a service.

```
  import type { 
    AccordionChildMap,
    AccordionStates,
    AccordionData,
    AccordionProps,
    AccordionKeys,
    AccordionAction,
    AccordionPanelState,
  } from '@/types/global';

  class AccordionServiceInstance {
    #childMap: AccordionChildMap;
    #datas: AccordionStates;
    #props: { [key: string] : AccordionProps };
    #actionHandlers: { [key: string] : AccordionAction }
    #nameIndex: number;
    
    constructor() {
      this.#childMap = {};
      this.#datas = {};
      this.#props = {};
      this.#nameIndex = 0;
      this.#actionHandlers = {};
    }

    registerParent(data: AccordionData, isVert: boolean, allOpen: boolean) : string {
      console.log("ParentHeight: " + data.height);
      const parentName = "accordion" + this.#nameIndex++;
      this.#props[parentName] = {
        isVert: isVert,
        allOpen: allOpen,
      } 
      this.#datas[parentName] = data;
      return parentName;
    }

    registerChild(childName: string, onChange: AccordionAction, headerHeight: number) : string {
      
      let foundParent = "";
      console.log("set headerHeight: " + headerHeight);
      
      const keys = Object.keys(this.#datas)
      for (let i=0; i < keys.length && foundParent == ""; i++) {
        const key = keys[i];
        const parentKeys = Object.keys(this.#datas[key].state);
        if (parentKeys.indexOf(childName) > -1) {
          foundParent = key;
          this.#childMap[childName] = key;
          this.#actionHandlers[childName] = onChange;
          this.#datas[foundParent].headerHeight = headerHeight;
        } else {
          console.log("AccordionService could not find parent for: " + childName);
        }
      }
      return foundParent;
    }

    getPanelHeight(childName: string) : string {
      const stateName = this.#childMap[childName];
      const data = this.#datas[stateName]
      const state = data.state;
      const props = this.#props[stateName];
      const childState = state[childName];
      const childCount = Object.keys(state).length;
      return (childState.disabled || 
        !childState.open) ? "0" :
          props.allOpen ? "auto" : (data.height - childCount * (data.headerHeight + 8) + "px");
    }

    getChildState(childName: string) : AccordionPanelState {
      const stateName = this.#childMap[childName];
      return this.#datas[stateName].state[childName];
    }

    getChildProps(childName: string) : AccordionProps {
      const stateName = this.#childMap[childName];
      return this.#props[stateName];
    }

    getData(parentName: string) : AccordionData {
      return this.#datas[parentName];
    }

    setHeight(parentName: string, height: number) : void {
      console.log("set height: " + height);
      this.#datas[parentName].height = height;
      const state = this.#datas[parentName].state;

      Object.keys(state).forEach( (x) => {
        console.log(x + "| open:" + state[x].open + "| disabled:" + state[x].disabled)
        this.#actionHandlers[x](state[x].open, state[x].disabled);
      });
    }

    changeChildState(childName : string, property: AccordionKeys, value: boolean) : void {
      const stateName = this.#childMap[childName];
      const props = this.#props[stateName];
      const state = this.#datas[stateName].state;
      if (!props.allOpen && property == "open" && value) {
        Object.keys(state).forEach( (x) => {
          if (x == childName) {
            state[x].open = true;
          } else {
            state[x].open = false;
          }
        });
      } else {
        state[childName].open = value;
      }
      Object.keys(state).forEach( (x) => {
        console.log(x + "| open:" + state[x].open + "| disabled:" + state[x].disabled)
        this.#actionHandlers[x](state[x].open, state[x].disabled);
      });
    }
  }

  export const AccordionService = new AccordionServiceInstance();
```

Using the control:

```
 <AccordionControl :state="{
    colorWheel: { open: true, disabled: false },
    colorMixer: { open: false, disabled: false },
    colorSelector: { open: false, disabled: true },
  }"
 >
   <AccordionPane panelName="colorWheel">
      <template v-slot:header>
        <h2>Create Color Scheme</h2>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:content>
        Stuff here
      </template>
    </AccordionPane>
    <AccordionPane panelName="colorMixer">
      <template v-slot:header>
        <h2>Color Mixer</h2>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:content>
        <h1>Stuff here</h1>
      </template>
    </AccordionPane>
    <AccordionPane panelName="colorSelector">
      <template v-slot:header>
        <h2>Assign / Select colors</h2>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:content>
        <h1>Stuff here</h1>
      </template>
    </AccordionPane>
  </AccordionControl>
```

There's a lot more that needs to be explained in the answer, such as the stylesheets and the the controls, so I hope you can see this:

edit: new public link, you should be able to see this.

https://codesandbox.io/p/github/geewhizbang/iconBuilder/main?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522panelType%2522%253A%2522TABS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clj0o2kvv000b356mxs0qrg76%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522panelType%2522%253A%2522TABS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clj0o2kvv000d356m2n227iv8%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clj0o2kvv000b356mxs0qrg76%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clj0o2kvv000b356mxs0qrg76%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clj1st09l00no356mzhtu2p2h%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clj0o2kvv000a356m5qfapa5a%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Frouter%252Findex.ts%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clj0o6qyd00dz356m24q2e1x1%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252F.codesandbox%252Ftasks.json%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clj1st09l00no356mzhtu2p2h%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clj0o2kvv000d356m2n227iv8%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clj0o2kvv000d356m2n227iv8%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clj0o2y5w006l356mlvlq3t5h%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clj0o2zf800bt356mgg70yn0j%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clj0o2zf800bt356mgg70yn0j%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D

I hope this is not a hack.